# new WP_Query(), have_posts() return false in user_register hook

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, user-registration

The $notifications->have_posts() return false, though I'm sure there are few posts of this custom type, in the database.

```
add_action('user_register','jq_after_user_register_hook', 10, 1);
function jq_after_user_register_hook( $user_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
    if ( isset( $user_meta->roles ) && is_array( $user_meta->roles ) && in_array('subscriber', $user_meta->roles) ) {

        $args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'sending_time',
                    'value' => 'on_registration',
                    'compare' => '=',
                )
            ),
            'post_type' => '_jq_notifications',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $notifications = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($notifications->have_posts()) : $notifications->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
        endwhile;
    }
}
```

PS:The same block of code (i.e. new WP_Query) works in wp_ajax action
`add_action( "wp_ajax__jq_admin_g_nos", "_jq_admin_get_notifications" );`

Comment: I have experience before that custom post types and taxonomies are actually not yet ready in certain hook. You may find out in this direction. Example, you you try 'init' hook to do the same thing to see if there is any results.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding `'post_status' => 'draft'` to the `$args` array, as below
`$args = array(
           'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'sending_time',
                    'value' => 'on_registration',
                    'compare' => '=',
                )
            ),
            'post_type' => '_jq_notifications',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        );`

The custom post type "_jq_notifications" default status was draft.

The documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) says

> post_status: Default value is ‘publish‘, but if the user is logged in, ‘private‘ is added. Public custom post statuses are also included by default. And if the query is run in an admin context (administration area or AJAX call), protected statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are ‘future‘, ‘draft‘ and ‘pending‘.